# stripe chekout not working when adding the headers and body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, stripe-payments

So when I delete the headers and body from my fetch request it is working great in local but when I add them I get no response at all . Is there anything I am doing wrong in this request ?
My frontend

```js
  const handleClick = async ({ title }) => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: title }),
      }
    );

    const session = await response.json();
    // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: session.id,
    });
    if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
    }
  };
```

My server request

```js
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title } = req.body;
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      shipping_address_collection: {
        allowed_countries: ["US", "CA", "FR", "ES", "GE", "SZ"],
      },
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      line_items: [
        {
          name: title,
          images: ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
          amount: 100 * 100,
          currency: "usd",
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: "payment",
      success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true`,
      cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
    });
    res.send({ id: session.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: When the headers and body are added and you get no response is there an error or warning in the browser console?

Comment: on my backend console i do not get any error response which is really weird but on the browser console I get the error "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: When that error happens does your server code create a Checkout Session?  Do you see one created in the Stripe Dashboard?

Comment: found it !! I was using both line : app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); and app.use(bodyParser.json()) and just kept the first one and it worked :)